# Retaining rounded rectangle shape - Flash CS5

Tags: adobe-flash, resize, shapes

I've got a rounded rectangle, I want to make it wider without distorting the corners round-ness, however when I just change the size of the shape, it distorts the corner's shape.

How can I do this? Do I need to just remake the shape in ActionScript dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the shape up for [9-slice scaling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7db9a.html).